# Why window.getComputedStyle in Flow returns `any` type?

Tags: flowtype

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) `getComputedStyle(element)` returns [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) object. But Flow tells that return type of method is `any`. Can I fix this without writing own type declaration?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there is any particular reason, just that it hasn't yet been given a better type. You can see in the [DOM libdef file](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/f581c7f0e5c638a2cb8da428f37964ef91f02664/lib/dom.js#L3966) that it is declared as returning `any`, and that line hasn't been touched in over four years.

This would be an easy first PR, if you are interested in improving it.